# docker-compose not passing env variables to PHP

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have the following set up and have tried all the ways that I can find to pass env variables to PHP but none of the them are working. Not sure what I have set up wrong. Ideally I want to be able to get the variable using $_SERVER['MY_ENV'], but I have also tried getenv('MY_ENV') with no success.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MY_ENV=dev
    command: php -S app:8000 -t public
    ports:
      - "8888:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
       - db
    networks:
      - myapp

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    command: mysqld --sql_mode="" --default-authentication plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - myapp

networks:
  myapp:
```

DockerFile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git cron
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

USER www

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is to make way for the upgrade, I need to get this running first. In my example is should be setting the environment variable into the container, not picking it up afterwards from an .env file. It needs to be collected from $_SERVER

Comment: Note the difference between how the environment vars are defined in the PHP container vs the Mysql container.

Comment: I have tried defining them both ways with no difference. I've tried everything I can find documented as explained.

Comment: @Sammitch [Docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) shows that as an option.

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose config` to see if it's defined? Another thing might be you need to restart your container to get the updated vars to be loaded.

Comment: Yes it is defined when running that command

Comment: Have you done an exec into a shell to verify there? Again, the container also needs to be restarted, it won't automatically see updates to the yml file. This is usually what I forget to do when I update an env setting.

Comment: I have been using docker-compose restart app after changes, I've also rebuild the image on a few occasions. I can exec into the container, how is best to check if the env variable is set?

Comment: I can see it set in the container using docker-compose exec app printenv. Any idea why it would not be bing picked up in the php code?

Comment: The image isn't going to matter. Have you tried looking at `$_ENV` to see if it's there? Realizing you're looking for it in `$_SERVER`, but just to check.

Comment: It is there, thank you!

Comment: I avoid using `$_SERVER` for env because it's easier to search and find uses of `$_ENV` that are only env vars. My two cents on that.

Comment: I spent the entire day on that, just happy to have a solution, you're a star!

Comment: That actually happened to me the first time... More like an hour of wth.